# Using ExtAudioFileWrite to write at the end of a file

Tags: core-audio, audiounit, remoteio, extaudiofile

I'm trying to open a file and append data to it using ExtAudioFileWrite. Now, creating/initial writing(on creation)/converting works just fine, but unfortunately I can't seem to be able to open  the file for writing afterwards. There is only one function that seems to open the file: `ExAudioFileOpenURL` but only for reading. So, how can I write at the end of a file if I'm not able to open the file for writing?

Comment: Did you try `AudioFileOpenURL` and then `ExtAudioFileWrapAudioFileID`?

Comment: Hello, did you succeed in appending to the end of the file? I am trying to do the same thing but can't have it working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, or not fully understanding your question. But, once you start writing to the file using ExtAudioFileWrite you can keep writing to it by calling the ExtAudioFileWrite again. I am about to venture into coding with no compiler, hopefully you will get the idea

Example:

```
....variables declaration and your logic.....

//1.Create File to write output
ExtAudioFileRef outputFile;

//+++++++ LOOP to append as many files as you want +++++++//

//2.Create file reference to files you want to merge
ExtAudioFileRef audioFileObject = 0;

//3.open the first file
ExtAudioFileOpenURL (firstFileURL, &audioFileObject);

//4.get file properties
AudioStreamBasicDescription AudioFileFormat = 0;
UInt64 numberOfPacketsToReadInCurrentFile = 0;
ExtAudioFileGetProperty(audioFileObject,
                        kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames,
                        sizeof(numberOfPacketsToReadInCurrentFile),
                        &numberOfPacketsToReadInCurrentFile
                        );

ExtAudioFileGetProperty(audioFileObject,
                        kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat,
                        sizeof(AudioFileFormat),
                        &AudioFileFormat
                        );
//5.Set destination ASBD
ExtAudioFileSetProperty(audioFileObject,
                        kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat,
                        sizeof (importFormat),
                        &importFormat
                        );

//6.Set/Create/Allocate Some Buffers
//use AudioFileFormat to setup your buffers accordingly

AudioBufferList theBufferList = 0 // bufferList setup (I dont remember that)

//7.Read the file into the buffer
ExtAudioFileRead(audioFileObject,&numberOfPacketsToReadInCurrentFile,theBufferList);

//8.Write the buffer to a File    
ExtAudioFileWrite(outputFile, numberOfPacketsToReadInCurrentFile, theBufferList);
free(theBufferList);

//if you want to append more files go to point 2 with the next file URL

//+++++++CLOSE LOOP+++++++++//

//once you are done.. just dispose the file and clean up everything left
ExtAudioFileDispose(outputFile);
```

This will not compile, I guess. But hopefully will help you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, if you keep the file open, it will work just fine. However, if you close it and then open again it will write from the very beginning. I solved the problem by using AudioFile directly, I don't think the extended version has this feature.

Comment: And if you read into a buffer, like in your example, memory will be an issue at some point (it was in my situation)

Comment: Like I said, I might not be completely understanding what you need. I am glad you figured it out though. Sorry I couldn't be of any help.

Comment: Np, sorry I didn't remove the question or answer it :)

Comment: Is there a way to obtain a ExtAudioFileRef after the app was killed in order to resume writing?